# how to label axis within radar chart with chart.js

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I would like to label the axis within an chart.js radar chart differently. The axis are labeled with numbers from 1 to 5 (see print screen). I would like to have instead of 1 = "No", 2 = "Basic", 3 = "Proficient" etc.

[image]

Is that somehow configurable with chart.js in a radar chart, e.g. by using chart.js options?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you provide a jsfiddle?

Comment: which version of chart js is this?

Comment: I'm using version 2.1.3

Answer (score 5):

Since you are using [Chart.js](http://www.chartjs.org) version 2.1.3, it will be very simple to achieve what you want.

In any chart (including the radar, the one you are using), labels on values are stored in `options.scale.ticks`.

Then, if you want to edit the way they are displayed, you must use Chart.js callbacks, like this :

```js
var options = {
    scale: {
        ticks: {
            beginAtZero: true,
            userCallback: function (value, index, values) {
                // Default callback
                return value;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Edit the `return` value with what you want.

---

Here is a [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dzg27yu3/), and also a fully working example using a simple array with the labels you want to display :

```js
var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext("2d");

var notations = {
  0: "",
  0.5: "",
  1: "no",
  1.5: "",
  2: "basic",
  2.5: "",
  3: "proficient",
  3.5: "",
  4: "great",
  4.5: "",
  5: "outstanding",
}

var data = {
  labels: ["Eating", "Drinking", "Sleeping", "Designing", "Coding", "Cycling", "Running"],
  datasets: [{
    label: "My First dataset",
    backgroundColor: "rgba(179,181,198,0.2)",
    borderColor: "rgba(179,181,198,1)",
    pointBackgroundColor: "rgba(179,181,198,1)",
    pointBorderColor: "#fff",
    pointHoverBackgroundColor: "#fff",
    pointHoverBorderColor: "rgba(179,181,198,1)",
    data: [3.25, 2.95, 4.5, 4.05, 2.8, 2.75, 2.0]
  }, {
    label: "My Second dataset",
    backgroundColor: "rgba(255,99,132,0.2)",
    borderColor: "rgba(255,99,132,1)",
    pointBackgroundColor: "rgba(255,99,132,1)",
    pointBorderColor: "#fff",
    pointHoverBackgroundColor: "#fff",
    pointHoverBorderColor: "rgba(255,99,132,1)",
    data: [1.4, 2.4, 2.0, 0.95, 4.8, 1.35, 5.0]
  }]
};

var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: "radar",
  data: data,
  options: {
    scale: {
      ticks: {
        beginAtZero: true,
        userCallback: function(value, index, values) {
          return notations[value];
        }
      }
    }
  }
});



console.log(myChart);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.1.6/Chart.js"></script>
<canvas id="myChart" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
```